# Why are there two IonHeader tags in the blank project scaffold?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I started an Ionic Framework project using this command:

```
ionic start myApp blank --type=react
```

The resulting `Home.tsx` file looks like this and includes two "almost" identical `<IonHeader>` tags.  From the [IonHeader documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/header), it says:

> It's important to note that ion-header needs to be the one of the three root elements of a page

My question is why there are two instances of `<IonHeader>` in the scaffolded `Home.tsx`? Running the app in the browser, there is only a single title visible.

```
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Home.css';

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>

        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Blank</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">Blank</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <ExploreContainer />
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first IonHeader is the defaupt one which is known for sure to you, the second one appears when scrolling down on ios, so that it more acts like ios native look.

The second header become over the first and on scroll to top most the default header appears again.

So you can remove the second one since as i remeber there is still a glitch in ots performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What is the "ots performance" issue you're talking about? Do you have a link to a bug or something you could post?

Comment: its* performance, i've recongized the bug my self, at the time of exchange between header 2 and header 1, a white blank header also gets in display for like a 250 ms or more, the bug is more to be like a glitch, it should work smoother and faster, but maybe now its better, i tested it a month ago when i was in my work but after corna i can't know if its solved or not.. but though you can keep it if you want, i'm as a programmer can see the glitch but user may not recognize it (may..).

Comment: Looking through the ionic framework docs for something completely unrelated I came across a section describing what your answer says.  The section is [Collapsible Large Titles](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/title#collapsible-large-titles).  The link supplies more details, but basically _"Ionic provides a way to create the collapsible titles that exist on stock iOS apps....The first IonHeader represents the "collapsed" state of your collapsible header, and the second IonHeader represents the "expanded" state of your collapsible header."_